# Does composer dump-autoload -o need to be run after setup:di:compile if composer install --optiomize-autoloader hase been run before

Tags: magento2, composer, autoloader

Every thing is in the title : Does `composer dump-autoload -o` really need to be run after `setup:di:compile` as the official document seem to pretend : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_perf-optimize.html

But if `composer install --optimize-autoloader` has been run before, the autoload dump is already done, i don't see relationship with `setup:di:compile` ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be run after `setup:di:compile` command, because it generates new classes and they will be not be optimized for autoloading

Comment: I know it generates new classes (in var/di var/generation for magento < 2.2 and generated/ for magento 2.2) , but  theses directories are not specified in the autoload list of the composer.json file, then i don't see any impact of composer autoloading on theses classes ?

Comment: @SylvainPRAS I know this is 3 years later than your comment, but `generated/code` is included now (currently I'm looking at Magento 2.3.3).

Comment: you're right, it has been added in 2.2.6 :-)